# add new post default view

Tags: posts, blog

Why do I get the view from the screenshot when trying to add a new post instead of the classic one?

How can I change it to the classic one?

[image]

Comment: do you speak about the new editor Gutenberg ? https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/

Comment: can I go back to the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Classic Editor plugin:

https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/